# what's wrong with Next.js?? it keeps returning unknown error -4094

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

my Next.js 13.4.9 returns what's wrong with Next.js?? it returns

{
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'D:\.next\static\chunks\app\main\page.js'
}

every single time when I save the page after editing, it shows on the terminal
here what I did and they don't work

1. clear npm cache
2. remove node_modules and npm install again
3. npm run dev again
4. upgrade npm
5. upgrade node.js
6. upgrade all depedencies
7. remove ._next file and run dev

all of these did not work and this error keep showing every single time...
help me please... I almost go back to the React.js... this is not right..
I am struggling with this issue for couple month.. help...